# MStest fails when called as a batch file from Coded ui

Tags: winforms, batch-file, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I have a batch file which is used to run mstest.Clicking on the batch file executes the file just fine. However when the same file is called from a win form application, mstest fails. This behaviour seems quirky.Could anyone provide any reasons for this.
I have used the following code to call it :

```
            Process myProcess = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new  ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\CodedUI\CommonAutomationFramework\Driver_batch.bat");
            myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
            myProcess.Start();
```

Comment: The working directory is probably not the same when launching using the application so the file references in the batch file are failing.  That is my guess without seeing the batch script.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is failing? The test(s) or MSTest itself?

Anyway a batch file executes commands on the command line interpreter (cmd).

In the process you're starting, maybe you should start 'cmd.exe' instead. Read the contents of the batch file and pass them a an addiction to 'cmd.exe'

Like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
Process process;

processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
(...)
```

Where your 'command' here is the text in the batch file.

You could also try this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"D:\CodedUI\CommonAutomationFramework\Driver_batch.bat");
```

Comment: The  mstest process starts, but the test fails immediately. I see the result as failed in the mstest console

Comment: Don't ask stuff in your answer!

Comment: Could this be because the coded ui test and the winform application from which I am calling the batch file, reside in the same solution ?

Comment: I don't think that makes a lot of sense. If the batch file works if you execute it manually. Did you try that approach of launching cmd.exe and pass the batch as text parameters to it?